# C Cannot Access Memory at Address

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to learning C, and I was practicing with memory allocations and pointers, however I've come a across a problem that I can't get around. When I debug the below code, I receive an error that states "Cannot Access Memory at Address" for line vowelStore[x] = vowelA;

```
char *DissVowel(char phrase[50])
{  
    char vowelStore[50];

    for(int x=0; x< strlen(phrase); x++)
    {
        switch(phrase[x])
        {
            char *vowelA = malloc(sizeof(*vowelA));

            case 'a':
                vowelA = phrase[x];
                vowelStore[x] = vowelA;
                free(vowelA);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return vowelStore;
}
```

Basically, this function takes in a array of characters(a string phrase), then cycles through each character, and if the current character is "a", a memory piece is allocated, and "a" will be stored in the allocated space. Next, the address of this space containing "a" will be stored in a separate array, which will contain several address. The function then returns this array of address.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `vowelA = phrase[x];` has overwritten the pointer to memory that was obtained from `malloc`, and will generated a compiler warning for being a different type. Once you have trashed the pointer obtained by `malloc` you cannot later `free` it. In any case `char *vowelA = malloc(sizeof(*vowelA));` allocates **1 byte** of memory.

Comment: A `char` array cannot store a `char *`. (Unrelated - or possibly related due to your incomprehension of pointers -, but `vowelA` itself does not need to be a `char *`, and it does not need to be `sizeof(any pointer)`.)

Comment: `char *vowelA = malloc(sizeof(*vowelA));` This may not be executed.

Comment: Turn up the warnings from the compiler.   The warnings you get will be self-explanatory.  There are multiple problems that potentially introduce undefined behaviour, such as assignments between variables of incompatible types, and returning the address of a local.  Eliminate the warnings, and most of the problems will go away.

Comment: With `return vowelStore;` you are returning a pointer to a local varaible that will go out of scope after the function exits. If the caller uses it that will be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: It *will* not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

```
char *DissVowel(char phrase[50])
```

This is legal but misleading. C does not actually have array parameters. If you define what looks like an array parameter, as you've done here, it's "adjusted" to become a pointer parameter -- and the length is quietly ignored. The above is exactly equivalent to:

```
char *DissVowel(char *phrase)
```

```
for(int x=0; x< strlen(phrase); x++)
```

This is legal but inefficient. `strlen()` has to scan the string from the beginning to find the terminating `'\0'` null character that marks the end of the string. You call `strlen` on each iteration. Either save the string length in a variable and test that in the condition, or use a different condition such as `phrase[x] != '\0'`. (A very minor point: `i` is a more conventional name for an iteration variable used as an index.)

```
    switch(phrase[x])
    {
        char *vowelA = malloc(sizeof(*vowelA));

        case 'a':
            /* ... */
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

A `switch` statement is essentially a computed `goto`. When the `switch` is executed, it jumps directly either to the `case 'a':` label or to the `default:` label, skipping over anything in between. Since this enters a new scope, memory is allocated for the pointer object `vowelA` itself, but its initialization is not executed, so `vowelA` has an indeterminate value.

```
return vowelStore;
```

`vowelStore` is a local array variable. In this context, it's "converted" to a pointer to the array's initial element, equivalent to `&vowelStore[0]`.  The array variable ceases to exist when you return from the function, so the value you're returning is a dangling pointer.

You should find out how to enable more warnings in your compiler; it should be able to warn you about at least some of these problems.